# Bootstrap - Textbox with two radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a small simple web app and having some trouble creating the radio buttons I want.

I want the user to be able to decide whether they want to input the dollar value or a percentage, that would then be used to calculate a dollar value.

I want the input text box to look similar to this example:

[image]

```
Here is a codepen example:
```

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/timbram/pen/aObPvX)

How can I get the radio buttons to be right on top of each other in bootstrap?  Or will I need to resort to custom css to get it done?

Answer (score 2):

`input` elements are by default displayed as `inline;`

You need to use `display:block` for them to show one on top of the other.

```
.input-group-addon input{
  display:block;
}
```

You'd also need to give a specific class to this input-group so you'll be able to use this layout specific to that class only and not all `input-group-addons`

Answer (score 1):

Since it is BootStrap, you could always wrap your radio boxes inside BootStrap classes like such. Or display block but the input height will stretch height further than adding bootstrap divs.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
       $<input type="checkbox" aria-label="...">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12">
       %<input type="checkbox" aria-label="...">
   </div>
</div>
```